# How to add a controlbar to the Flex Spark Panel component just below to the title bar

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flex-spark

I am trying to add a controlbar to the Flex Spark Panel component just below to the title bar. It is to works as the controlbar of the spark controlbar. So that I can add components to the To implement it I have created a skin and a as3 class extending the spark class. But it is not working. Can any one help me out. I am new to spark components. I need help.

The Skin: CustoPanel\src\skin\CustomPanelSkinHeaderControlBar.mxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--

ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED
Copyright 2008 Adobe Systems Incorporated
All Rights Reserved.

NOTICE: Adobe permits you to use, modify, and distribute this file
in accordance with the terms of the license agreement accompanying it.

-->

<!--- The default skin class for a Spark Panel container.  

    @see spark.components.Panel

    @langversion 3.0
    @playerversion Flash 10
    @playerversion AIR 1.5
    @productversion Flex 4
-->
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
             xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009"
             minWidth="131" minHeight="127" blendMode="normal" mouseEnabled="false"
             alpha.disabled="0.5"
             alpha.disabledWithControlAndHeaderBar="0.5"
             alpha.disabledWithControlBar="0.5"
             alpha.disabledWithHeaderBar="0.5">

    <fx:Metadata>
        <![CDATA[ 
        /** 
         * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
         */
        /* [HostComponent("spark.components.Panel")] */
        [HostComponent("customCompo.ExtPanel")]
        ]]>
    </fx:Metadata> 

    <fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
        <![CDATA[
        import mx.core.FlexVersion;

        /* Define the skin elements that should not be colorized. 
        For panel, border and title background are skinned, but the content area, background, border, and title text are not. */
        /* static private const exclusions:Array = ["background", "titleDisplay", "contentGroup", "controlBarGroup", "border"]; */
        static private const exclusions:Array = ["background", "titleDisplay", "contentGroup", "controlBarGroup", "headerControlBarGroup", "border"];

        /* exclusions before Flex 4.5 for backwards-compatibility purposes */
        /* static private const exclusions_4_0:Array = ["background", "titleDisplay", "contentGroup", "controlBarGroup"]; */
        static private const exclusions_4_0:Array = ["background", "titleDisplay", "contentGroup", "controlBarGroup", "headerControlBarGroup"];

        /**
         * @private
         */
        override public function get colorizeExclusions():Array 
        {
            // Since border is styleable via borderColor, no need to allow chromeColor to affect
            // the border.  This is wrapped in a compatibility flag since this change was added  
            // in Flex 4.5
            if (FlexVersion.compatibilityVersion < FlexVersion.VERSION_4_5)
            {
                return exclusions_4_0;
            }

            return exclusions;
        }

        /**
         * @private
         */
        override protected function initializationComplete():void
        {
            useChromeColor = true;
            super.initializationComplete();
        }

        /**
         * @private
         */
        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            if (getStyle("borderVisible") == true)
            {
                border.visible = true;
                background.left = background.top = background.right = background.bottom = 1;
                contents.left = contents.top = contents.right = contents.bottom = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                border.visible = false;
                background.left = background.top = background.right = background.bottom = 0;
                contents.left = contents.top = contents.right = contents.bottom = 0;
            }

            dropShadow.visible = getStyle("dropShadowVisible");

            var cr:Number = getStyle("cornerRadius");
            var withControls:Boolean = 
                (currentState == "disabledWithControlBar" || 
                 currentState == "normalWithControlBar");

            if (cornerRadius != cr)
            {
                cornerRadius = cr;

                dropShadow.tlRadius = cornerRadius;
                dropShadow.trRadius = cornerRadius;
                dropShadow.blRadius = withControls ? cornerRadius : 0;
                dropShadow.brRadius = withControls ? cornerRadius : 0;

                setPartCornerRadii(topMaskRect, withControls); 
                setPartCornerRadii(border, withControls); 
                setPartCornerRadii(background, withControls);                
            }

            if (bottomMaskRect) setPartCornerRadii(bottomMaskRect, withControls); 

            borderStroke.color = getStyle("borderColor");
            borderStroke.alpha = getStyle("borderAlpha");
            backgroundFill.color = getStyle("backgroundColor");
            backgroundFill.alpha = getStyle("backgroundAlpha");

            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        }

        /**
         * @private
         */  
        private function setPartCornerRadii(target:Rect, includeBottom:Boolean):void
        {            
            target.topLeftRadiusX = cornerRadius;
            target.topRightRadiusX = cornerRadius;
            target.bottomLeftRadiusX = includeBottom ? cornerRadius : 0;
            target.bottomRightRadiusX = includeBottom ? cornerRadius : 0;
        }

        private var cornerRadius:Number;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
        <s:State name="normalWithControlBar" stateGroups="withControls" />
        <s:State name="disabledWithControlBar" stateGroups="withControls" />
        <s:State name="normalWithControlAndHeaderbar" stateGroups="withControls" />
        <s:State name="disabledWithControlAndHeaderBar" stateGroups="withControls" />
        <s:State name="normalWithHeaderBar"/>
        <s:State name="disabledWithHeaderBar"/>
    </s:states>

    <!-- drop shadow can't be hittable so it stays sibling of other graphics -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:RectangularDropShadow id="dropShadow" blurX="20" blurY="20" alpha="0.32" distance="11" 
                             angle="90" color="#000000" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0"/>

    <!-- drop shadow can't be hittable so all other graphics go in this group -->
    <s:Group left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">

        <!-- top group mask -->
        <!--- @private -->
        <s:Group left="1" top="1" right="1" bottom="1" id="topGroupMask" >
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:Rect id="topMaskRect" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0">
                <s:fill>
                    <s:SolidColor alpha="0"/>
                </s:fill>
            </s:Rect>
        </s:Group>

        <!-- bottom group mask -->
        <!--- @private -->
        <s:Group left="1" top="1" right="1" bottom="1" id="bottomGroupMask" 
                 includeIn="disabledWithControlAndHeaderBar,disabledWithControlBar,normalWithControlAndHeaderbar,normalWithControlBar">
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:Rect id="bottomMaskRect" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0">
                <s:fill>
                    <s:SolidColor alpha="0"/>
                </s:fill>
            </s:Rect>
        </s:Group>

        <!-- layer 1: border -->
        <!--- @private -->
        <s:Rect id="border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" >
            <s:stroke>
                <!--- @private -->
                <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" weight="1" />
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Rect>

        <!-- layer 2: background fill -->
        <!--- Defines the appearance of the PanelSkin class's background. -->
        <s:Rect id="background" left="1" top="1" right="1" bottom="1">
            <s:fill>
                <!--- @private
                      Defines the  PanelSkin class's background fill. The default color is 0xFFFFFF. -->
                <s:SolidColor id="backgroundFill" color="#FFFFFF"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>

        <!-- layer 3: contents -->
        <!--- Contains the vertical stack of titlebar content and controlbar. -->
        <s:Group left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" id="contents">
            <s:layout>
                <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" horizontalAlign="justify" />
            </s:layout>

            <!--- @private -->
            <s:Group id="topGroupMaskImp" mask="{topGroupMask}">

                <!-- layer 0: title bar fill -->
                <!--- @private -->
                <s:Rect id="tbFill" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="1">
                    <s:fill>
                        <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                            <s:GradientEntry color="0xE2E2E2" />
                            <s:GradientEntry color="0xD9D9D9" />
                        </s:LinearGradient>
                    </s:fill>
                </s:Rect>

                <!-- layer 1: title bar highlight -->
                <!--- @private -->
                <s:Rect id="tbHilite" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
                    <s:stroke>
                        <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                            <s:GradientEntry color="0xEAEAEA" />
                            <s:GradientEntry color="0xD9D9D9" />
                        </s:LinearGradientStroke>
                    </s:stroke>
                </s:Rect>

                <!-- layer 2: title bar divider -->
                <!--- @private -->
                <s:Rect id="tbDiv" left="0" right="0" height="1" bottom="0">
                    <s:fill>
                        <s:SolidColor color="0xC0C0C0" />
                    </s:fill>
                </s:Rect>

                <!-- layer 3: text -->
                <!--- @copy spark.components.Panel#titleDisplay -->
                <s:Label id="titleDisplay" maxDisplayedLines="1"
                         left="9" right="3" top="1" bottom="0" minHeight="20"
                         verticalAlign="middle" textAlign="start" fontWeight="bold">
                </s:Label>
            </s:Group>

            <!--
                Note: setting the minimum size to 0 here so that changes to the host component's
                size will not be thwarted by this skin part's minimum size.   This is a compromise,
                more about it here: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-21143
            -->

            <!--Header ControlBar-->
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:Group id="topGroup" minWidth="0" minHeight="0"
                     includeIn="normalWithControlAndHeaderbar,disabledWithControlAndHeaderBar,normalWithHeaderBar,disabledWithHeaderBar" >

                <s:Group left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" mask="{bottomGroupMask}">

                    <!-- layer 0: control top bar divider line -->
                    <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" height="1" alpha="0.22">
                        <s:fill>
                            <s:SolidColor color="0x000000" />
                        </s:fill>
                    </s:Rect>

                    <!-- layer 1: control top bar highlight -->
                    <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="1" bottom="0">
                        <s:stroke>
                            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xE5E5E5" />
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xD8D8D8" />
                            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
                        </s:stroke>
                    </s:Rect>

                    <!-- layer 2: control top bar fill -->
                    <s:Rect left="1" right="1" top="2" bottom="1">
                        <s:fill>
                            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xDADADA" />
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xC5C5C5" />
                            </s:LinearGradient>
                        </s:fill>
                    </s:Rect>
                </s:Group>
                <!-- layer 3: top control bar -->
                <!--- @copy spark.components.Panel#controlBarTopGroup -->
                <s:Group id="headerControlBarGroup" left="0" right="0" top="1" bottom="1" minWidth="0" minHeight="0">
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:HorizontalLayout paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" paddingTop="3" paddingBottom="3" gap="10" />
                    </s:layout>
                </s:Group>
            </s:Group>

            <!--x-Header control Bar-->

            <!--- @copy spark.components.SkinnableContainer#contentGroup -->
            <s:Group id="contentGroup" width="100%" height="100%" minWidth="0" minHeight="0">
            </s:Group>

            <!--- @private -->
            <s:Group id="bottomGroup" minWidth="0" minHeight="0"
                     includeIn="disabledWithControlAndHeaderBar,disabledWithControlBar,normalWithControlAndHeaderbar,normalWithControlBar" >

                <s:Group left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" mask="{bottomGroupMask}">

                    <!-- layer 0: control bar divider line -->
                    <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" height="1" alpha="0.22">
                        <s:fill>
                            <s:SolidColor color="0x000000" />
                        </s:fill>
                    </s:Rect>

                    <!-- layer 1: control bar highlight -->
                    <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="1" bottom="0">
                        <s:stroke>
                            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xE5E5E5" />
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xD8D8D8" />
                            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
                        </s:stroke>
                    </s:Rect>

                    <!-- layer 2: control bar fill -->
                    <s:Rect left="1" right="1" top="2" bottom="1">
                        <s:fill>
                            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xDADADA" />
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xC5C5C5" />
                            </s:LinearGradient>
                        </s:fill>
                    </s:Rect>
                </s:Group>
                <!-- layer 3: control bar -->
                <!--- @copy spark.components.Panel#controlBarGroup -->
                <s:Group id="controlBarGroup" left="0" right="0" top="1" bottom="1" minWidth="0" minHeight="0">
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:HorizontalLayout paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" paddingTop="7" paddingBottom="7" gap="10" />
                    </s:layout>
                </s:Group>
            </s:Group>
        </s:Group> <!--skl oph e-->
    </s:Group>
</s:SparkSkin>
```

The custom panel class:

```
    package customCompo
{
    import mx.core.mx_internal;
    import mx.utils.BitFlagUtil;

    import spark.components.Group;
    import spark.components.Panel;
    import spark.layouts.supportClasses.LayoutBase;

    use namespace mx_internal;

    [SkinState("normalWithControlAndHeaderbar")]

    [SkinState("disabledWithControlAndHeaderBar")]

    [SkinState("normalWithHeaderBar")]

    [SkinState("disabledWithHeaderBar")]

    [AccessibilityClass(implementation="spark.accessibility.PanelAccImpl")]


    public class ExtPanel extends Panel
    {
        public function ExtPanel()
        {
            super();
        }

        mx_internal static const HEADER_CONTROLBAR_PROPERTY_FLAG:uint = 1 << 0;
        mx_internal static const HEADER_LAYOUT_PROPERTY_FLAG:uint = 1 << 1;
        mx_internal static const HEADER_VISIBLE_PROPERTY_FLAG:uint = 1 << 2;

        mx_internal var headerControlBarGroupProperties:Object = { visible: true };

        public var headerControlBarGroup:Group;

        //----------------------------------
        //  headerControlBarContent
        //---------------------------------- 

        [ArrayElementType("mx.core.IVisualElement")]

        public function get headerControlBarContent():Array
        {
            if (headerControlBarGroup)
                return headerControlBarGroup.getMXMLContent();
            else
                return headerControlBarGroupProperties.controlBarContent;
        }

        /**
         *  @private
         */
        public function set headerControlBarContent(value:Array):void
        {
            if (headerControlBarGroup)
            {
                headerControlBarGroup.mxmlContent = value;
                headerControlBarGroupProperties = BitFlagUtil.update(headerControlBarGroupProperties as uint, 
                    HEADER_CONTROLBAR_PROPERTY_FLAG, value != null);
            }
            else
                headerControlBarGroupProperties.headerControlBarContent = value;

            invalidateSkinState();
        }

        //----------------------------------
        //  headerControlBarLayout
        //---------------------------------- 

        public function get headerControlBarLayout():LayoutBase
        {
            return (headerControlBarGroup) 
            ? headerControlBarGroup.layout 
                : headerControlBarGroupProperties.layout;
        }

        /**
         *  @private
         */
        public function set headerControlBarLayout(value:LayoutBase):void
        {
            if (headerControlBarGroup)
            {
                headerControlBarGroup.layout = value;
                headerControlBarGroupProperties = BitFlagUtil.update(headerControlBarGroupProperties as uint, 
                    HEADER_LAYOUT_PROPERTY_FLAG, true);
            }
            else
                headerControlBarGroupProperties.layout = value;
        }

        //----------------------------------
        //  headerControlBarVisible
        //---------------------------------- 

        public function get headerControlBarVisible():Boolean
        {
            return (headerControlBarGroup) 
            ? headerControlBarGroup.visible 
                : headerControlBarGroupProperties.visible;
        }

        /**
         *  @private
         */
        public function set headerControlBarVisible(value:Boolean):void
        {
            if (headerControlBarGroup)
            {
                headerControlBarGroup.visible = value;
                headerControlBarGroupProperties = BitFlagUtil.update(headerControlBarGroupProperties as uint, 
                    HEADER_VISIBLE_PROPERTY_FLAG, value);
            }
            else
                headerControlBarGroupProperties.visible = value;

            invalidateSkinState();
            if (skin)
                skin.invalidateSize();
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        //  Overridden methods
        //
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         *  @private
         */
        /*override protected function initializeAccessibility():void
        {
            if (Panel.createAccessibilityImplementation != null)
                Panel.createAccessibilityImplementation(this);
        }*/

        /**
         *  @private
         */
        override protected function partAdded(partName:String, instance:Object):void
        {
            super.partAdded(partName, instance);

            /*if (instance == titleDisplay)
            {
                titleDisplay.text = title;
            }
            else if (instance == controlBarGroup)*/

            if (instance == headerControlBarGroup)
            {
                // copy proxied values from controlBarGroupProperties (if set) to contentGroup
                var newHeaderControlBarGroupProperties:uint = 0;

                if (headerControlBarGroupProperties.headerControlBarContent !== undefined)
                {
                    headerControlBarGroup.mxmlContent = headerControlBarGroupProperties.headerControlBarContent;
                    newHeaderControlBarGroupProperties = BitFlagUtil.update(newHeaderControlBarGroupProperties, 
                        HEADER_CONTROLBAR_PROPERTY_FLAG, true);
                }

                if (headerControlBarGroupProperties.layout !== undefined)
                {
                    headerControlBarGroup.layout = headerControlBarGroupProperties.layout;
                    newHeaderControlBarGroupProperties = BitFlagUtil.update(newHeaderControlBarGroupProperties, 
                        HEADER_LAYOUT_PROPERTY_FLAG, true);
                }

                if (headerControlBarGroupProperties.visible !== undefined)
                {
                    headerControlBarGroup.visible = headerControlBarGroupProperties.visible;
                    newHeaderControlBarGroupProperties = BitFlagUtil.update(newHeaderControlBarGroupProperties, 
                        HEADER_VISIBLE_PROPERTY_FLAG, true);
                }

                headerControlBarGroupProperties = newHeaderControlBarGroupProperties;
            }
        }

        override protected function partRemoved(partName:String, instance:Object):void
        {
            super.partRemoved(partName, instance);

            if (instance == headerControlBarGroup)
            {
                // copy proxied values from contentGroup (if explicitely set) to contentGroupProperties

                var newHeaderControlBarGroupProperties:Object = {};

                if (BitFlagUtil.isSet(controlBarGroupProperties as uint, HEADER_CONTROLBAR_PROPERTY_FLAG))
                    newHeaderControlBarGroupProperties.headerControlBarContent = headerControlBarGroup.getMXMLContent();

                if (BitFlagUtil.isSet(controlBarGroupProperties as uint, HEADER_LAYOUT_PROPERTY_FLAG))
                    newHeaderControlBarGroupProperties.layout = headerControlBarGroup.layout;

                if (BitFlagUtil.isSet(controlBarGroupProperties as uint, HEADER_VISIBLE_PROPERTY_FLAG))
                    newHeaderControlBarGroupProperties.visible = headerControlBarGroup.visible;

                headerControlBarGroupProperties = newHeaderControlBarGroupProperties;

                headerControlBarGroup.mxmlContent = null;
                headerControlBarGroup.layout = null;
            }
        }

        override protected function getCurrentSkinState():String
        {
            var state:String = enabled ? "normal" : "disabled";
            if (headerControlBarGroup)
            {
                if (BitFlagUtil.isSet(headerControlBarGroupProperties as uint, HEADER_CONTROLBAR_PROPERTY_FLAG) &&
                    BitFlagUtil.isSet(headerControlBarGroupProperties as uint, HEADER_VISIBLE_PROPERTY_FLAG))
                    state += "WithHeaderBar";
            }
            else
            {
                if (headerControlBarGroupProperties.headerCcontrolBarContent &&
                    headerControlBarGroupProperties.visible)
                    state += "WithHeaderBar";
            }
            return state;
        }

    }
}
```

The application :

```
    <s:HGroup width="100%" horizontalAlign="center">

    <customCompo:ExtPanel width="400" height="200" title="RABBIT :" skinClass="skin.CustomPanelSkinHeaderControlBar">

            <customCompo:headerControlBarContent>
                <s:Label text="Peacock" />

            </customCompo:headerControlBarContent>
        </customCompo:ExtPanel>


    </s:HGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody. I have been able to solve it.

The extended panel class: PanelWithHeaderBar.as

```
package components.panelWithHeader
{
    import mx.core.mx_internal;
    import mx.utils.BitFlagUtil;

    import spark.components.Group;
    import spark.components.Panel;
    import spark.layouts.supportClasses.LayoutBase;

    use namespace mx_internal;

    public class PanelWithHeaderBar extends Panel
    {
        mx_internal static const HEADERBAR_PROPERTY_FLAG:uint = 1 << 0;

        mx_internal var headerBarGroupProperties:Object = { visible: true };

        /*Adding headerBar optional skin part */
        [SkinPart(required="false")]
        public var headerBarGroup:Group;

        public function PanelWithHeaderBar()
        {
            super();
        }

        /*Adding new headerBar field indicating if panel adds headerBar (invalidating skin state in setter)*/
        public function get headerBarContent():Array
        {
            if (headerBarGroup)
                return headerBarGroup.getMXMLContent();
            else
                return headerBarGroupProperties.headerBarContent;
        }
        public function set headerBarContent(value:Array):void
        {
            if (headerBarGroup)
            {
                headerBarGroup.mxmlContent = value;
                headerBarGroupProperties = BitFlagUtil.update(headerBarGroupProperties as uint, 
                                                CONTROLBAR_PROPERTY_FLAG, value != null);
            }
            else
                headerBarGroupProperties.headerBarContent = value;

            invalidateSkinState();
        }

        /* Header Bar Layout*/
        public function get headerbarLayout():LayoutBase
        {
            return (headerBarGroup) 
                ? headerBarGroup.layout 
                : headerBarGroupProperties.layout;
        }

        /**
         *  @private
         */
        public function set headerbarLayout(value:LayoutBase):void
        {
            if (headerBarGroup)
            {
                headerBarGroup.layout = value;
                headerBarGroupProperties = BitFlagUtil.update(headerBarGroupProperties as uint, 
                                            LAYOUT_PROPERTY_FLAG, true);
            }
            else
                headerBarGroupProperties.layout = value;
        }

        /* Header Bar Visiblity*/

        public function get headerBarVisible():Boolean
        {
            return (headerBarGroup) 
                ? headerBarGroup.visible 
                : headerBarGroupProperties.visible;
        }

        /**
         *  @private
         */
        public function set headerBarVisible(value:Boolean):void
        {
            if (headerBarGroup)
            {
                headerBarGroup.visible = value;
                headerBarGroupProperties = BitFlagUtil.update(headerBarGroupProperties as uint, 
                    VISIBLE_PROPERTY_FLAG, value);
            }
            else
                headerBarGroupProperties.visible = value;

            invalidateSkinState();
            if (skin)
                skin.invalidateSize();
        }

        /*Overriding partAdded()/partRemoved() functions to add headerBar event handler */
        override protected function partAdded(partName:String, instance:Object):void
        {
            super.partAdded(partName, instance);

            if (instance == headerBarGroup)
            {
                // copy proxied values from controlBarGroupProperties (if set) to contentGroup
                var newHeaderBarGroupProperties:uint = 0;

                if (headerBarGroupProperties.headerBarContent !== undefined)
                {
                    headerBarGroup.mxmlContent = headerBarGroupProperties.headerBarContent;
                    newHeaderBarGroupProperties = BitFlagUtil.update(newHeaderBarGroupProperties, 
                        CONTROLBAR_PROPERTY_FLAG, true);
                }

                if (headerBarGroupProperties.layout !== undefined)
                {
                    headerBarGroup.layout = headerBarGroupProperties.layout;
                    newHeaderBarGroupProperties = BitFlagUtil.update(newHeaderBarGroupProperties, 
                        LAYOUT_PROPERTY_FLAG, true);
                }

                if (headerBarGroupProperties.visible !== undefined)
                {
                    headerBarGroup.visible = headerBarGroupProperties.visible;
                    newHeaderBarGroupProperties = BitFlagUtil.update(newHeaderBarGroupProperties, 
                        VISIBLE_PROPERTY_FLAG, true);
                }

                headerBarGroupProperties = newHeaderBarGroupProperties;
            }
        }

        /**
         *  @private
         *  
         *  @langversion 3.0
         *  @playerversion Flash 10
         *  @playerversion AIR 1.5
         *  @productversion Flex 4
         */
        override protected function partRemoved(partName:String, instance:Object):void
        {
            super.partRemoved(partName, instance);

            if (instance == headerBarGroup)
            {
                // copy proxied values from contentGroup (if explicitely set) to contentGroupProperties

                var newHeaderBarGroupProperties:Object = {};

                if (BitFlagUtil.isSet(headerBarGroupProperties as uint, HEADERBAR_PROPERTY_FLAG))
                    newHeaderBarGroupProperties.headerBarContent = headerBarGroup.getMXMLContent();

                if (BitFlagUtil.isSet(headerBarGroupProperties as uint, LAYOUT_PROPERTY_FLAG))
                    newHeaderBarGroupProperties.layout = headerBarGroup.layout;

                if (BitFlagUtil.isSet(headerBarGroupProperties as uint, VISIBLE_PROPERTY_FLAG))
                    newHeaderBarGroupProperties.visible = headerBarGroup.visible;

                headerBarGroupProperties = newHeaderBarGroupProperties;

                headerBarGroup.mxmlContent = null;
                headerBarGroup.layout = null;
            }
        }

        /**
         *  @private
         *  
         *  @langversion 3.0
         *  @playerversion Flash 10
         *  @playerversion AIR 1.5
         *  @productversion Flex 4
         */
        override protected function getCurrentSkinState():String
        {
            var state:String = enabled ? "normal" : "disabled";
            if (headerBarGroup)
            {
                if (BitFlagUtil.isSet(headerBarGroupProperties as uint, HEADERBAR_PROPERTY_FLAG) &&
                    BitFlagUtil.isSet(headerBarGroupProperties as uint, VISIBLE_PROPERTY_FLAG))
                    state += "WithHeaderBar";
            }
            else
            {
                if (headerBarGroupProperties.headerBarContent &&
                    headerBarGroupProperties.visible)
                    state += "WithHeaderBar";
            }
            if (controlBarGroup)
            {
                if (BitFlagUtil.isSet(controlBarGroupProperties as uint, CONTROLBAR_PROPERTY_FLAG) &&
                    BitFlagUtil.isSet(controlBarGroupProperties as uint, VISIBLE_PROPERTY_FLAG))
                    state += "WithControlBar";
            }
            else
            {
                if (controlBarGroupProperties.controlBarContent &&
                    controlBarGroupProperties.visible)
                    state += "WithControlBar";
            }

            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

The skin for the panel : PanelWithHeaderBarSkin.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--

ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED
Copyright 2008 Adobe Systems Incorporated
All Rights Reserved.

NOTICE: Adobe permits you to use, modify, and distribute this file
in accordance with the terms of the license agreement accompanying it.

-->

<!--- The default skin class for a Spark Panel container.  

    @see spark.components.Panel

    @langversion 3.0
    @playerversion Flash 10
    @playerversion AIR 1.5
    @productversion Flex 4
-->
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" blendMode="normal" mouseEnabled="false" 
    minWidth="131" minHeight="127" alpha.disabled="0.5" alpha.disabledWithControlBar="0.5">
    <fx:Metadata>[HostComponent("components.panelWithHeader.PanelWithHeaderBar")]</fx:Metadata>

    <fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
        /* Define the skin elements that should not be colorized. 
        For panel, border and title background are skinned, but the content area and title text are not. */
        static private const exclusions:Array = ["background", "titleDisplay", "contentGroup", "controlBarGroup", "headerBarGroup"];

        /**
         * @private
         */  
        override public function get colorizeExclusions():Array {return exclusions;}

        /**
         * @private
         */
        override protected function initializationComplete():void
        {
            useChromeColor = true;
            super.initializationComplete();
        }

        /**
         * @private
         */
        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            if (getStyle("borderVisible") == true)
            {
                border.visible = true;
                background.left = background.top = background.right = background.bottom = 1;
                contents.left = contents.top = contents.right = contents.bottom = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                border.visible = false;
                background.left = background.top = background.right = background.bottom = 0;
                contents.left = contents.top = contents.right = contents.bottom = 0;
            }

            dropShadow.visible = getStyle("dropShadowVisible");

            var cr:Number = getStyle("cornerRadius");
            var withControls:Boolean = 
                (currentState == "disabledWithControlBar" || 
                 currentState == "normalWithControlBar"||
                 currentState == "disabledWithHeaderBar" ||
                 currentState == "normalWithHeaderBar" ||
                 currentState == "disabledWithHeaderBarWithControlBar" ||
                 currentState == "normalWithHeaderBarWithControlBar");

            if (cornerRadius != cr)
            {
                cornerRadius = cr;

                dropShadow.tlRadius = cornerRadius;
                dropShadow.trRadius = cornerRadius;
                dropShadow.blRadius = withControls ? cornerRadius : 0;
                dropShadow.brRadius = withControls ? cornerRadius : 0;

                setPartCornerRadii(topMaskRect, withControls); 
                setPartCornerRadii(border, withControls); 
                setPartCornerRadii(background, withControls);                
            }

            if (bottomMaskRect) setPartCornerRadii(bottomMaskRect, withControls); 

            borderStroke.color = getStyle("borderColor");
            borderStroke.alpha = getStyle("borderAlpha");
            backgroundFill.color = getStyle("backgroundColor");
            backgroundFill.alpha = getStyle("backgroundAlpha");

            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        }

        /**
         * @private
         */  
        private function setPartCornerRadii(target:Rect, includeBottom:Boolean):void
        {            
            target.topLeftRadiusX = cornerRadius;
            target.topRightRadiusX = cornerRadius;
            target.bottomLeftRadiusX = includeBottom ? cornerRadius : 0;
            target.bottomRightRadiusX = includeBottom ? cornerRadius : 0;
        }

        private var cornerRadius:Number;
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
        <s:State name="normalWithControlBar" stateGroups="withControls" />
        <s:State name="disabledWithControlBar" stateGroups="withControls" />
        <s:State name="normalWithHeaderBar" stateGroups="withControls" />
        <s:State name="disabledWithHeaderBar" stateGroups="withControls" />
        <s:State name="normalWithHeaderBarWithControlBar" stateGroups="withControls" />
        <s:State name="disabledWithHeaderBarWithControlBar" stateGroups="withControls" />
    </s:states>

    <!-- drop shadow can't be hittable so it stays sibling of other graphics -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:RectangularDropShadow id="dropShadow" blurX="20" blurY="20" alpha="0.32" distance="11" 
                             angle="90" color="#000000" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0"/>

    <!-- drop shadow can't be hittable so all other graphics go in this group -->
    <s:Group left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">

        <!-- top group mask -->
        <!--- @private -->
        <s:Group left="1" top="1" right="1" bottom="1" id="topGroupMask" >
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:Rect id="topMaskRect" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0">
                <s:fill>
                    <s:SolidColor alpha="0"/>
                </s:fill>
            </s:Rect>
        </s:Group>

        <!-- bottom group mask -->
        <!--- @private -->
        <s:Group left="1" top="1" right="1" bottom="1" id="bottomGroupMask" 
                 includeIn="normalWithControlBar, disabledWithControlBar">
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:Rect id="bottomMaskRect" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0">
                <s:fill>
                    <s:SolidColor alpha="0"/>
                </s:fill>
            </s:Rect>
        </s:Group>

        <!-- layer 1: border -->
        <!--- @private -->
        <s:Rect id="border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" >
            <s:stroke>
                <!--- @private -->
                <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" weight="1" />
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Rect>

        <!-- layer 2: background fill -->
        <!--- Defines the appearance of the PanelSkin class's background. -->
        <s:Rect id="background" left="1" top="1" right="1" bottom="1">
            <s:fill>
                <!--- @private
                      Defines the  PanelSkin class's background fill. The default color is 0xFFFFFF. -->
                <s:SolidColor id="backgroundFill" color="#FFFFFF"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>

        <!-- layer 3: contents -->
        <!--- Contains the vertical stack of titlebar content and controlbar. -->
        <s:Group left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" id="contents">
            <s:layout>
                <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" horizontalAlign="justify" />
            </s:layout>

            <!--- @private -->
            <s:Group id="topGroup" mask="{topGroupMask}">

                <!-- layer 0: title bar fill -->
                <!--- @private -->
                <s:Rect id="tbFill" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="1">
                    <s:fill>
                        <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                            <s:GradientEntry color="0xE2E2E2" />
                            <s:GradientEntry color="0xD9D9D9" />
                        </s:LinearGradient>
                    </s:fill>
                </s:Rect>

                <!-- layer 1: title bar highlight -->
                <!--- @private -->
                <s:Rect id="tbHilite" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
                    <s:stroke>
                        <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                            <s:GradientEntry color="0xEAEAEA" />
                            <s:GradientEntry color="0xD9D9D9" />
                        </s:LinearGradientStroke>
                    </s:stroke>
                </s:Rect>

                <!-- layer 2: title bar divider -->
                <!--- @private -->
                <s:Rect id="tbDiv" left="0" right="0" height="1" bottom="0">
                    <s:fill>
                        <s:SolidColor color="0xC0C0C0" />
                    </s:fill>
                </s:Rect>

                <!-- layer 3: text -->
                <!--- @copy spark.components.Panel#titleDisplay -->
                <s:Label id="titleDisplay" maxDisplayedLines="1"
                         left="9" right="3" top="1" bottom="0" minHeight="20"
                         verticalAlign="middle" textAlign="start" fontWeight="bold">
                </s:Label>
            </s:Group>

            <!--
                Note: setting the minimum size to 0 here so that changes to the host component's
                size will not be thwarted by this skin part's minimum size.   This is a compromise,
                more about it here: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-21143
            -->
            <s:Group id="topHeaderGroup" minWidth="0" minHeight="0"
                     includeIn="normalWithHeaderBar, disabledWithHeaderBar, disabledWithHeaderBarWithControlBar, normalWithHeaderBarWithControlBar">

                <s:Group left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" mask="{topGroupMask}">

                    <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
                        <s:stroke>
                            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xE5E5E5" />
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xD8D8D8" />
                            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
                        </s:stroke>
                    </s:Rect>

                    <s:Rect left="1" right="1" top="0" bottom="1">
                        <s:fill>
                            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xDADADA" />
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xC5C5C5" />
                            </s:LinearGradient>
                        </s:fill>
                    </s:Rect>
                </s:Group>

                <!-- layer 0: header control bar -->
                <!--- @copy spark.components.Panel#headerBarGroup -->
                <s:Group id="headerBarGroup" left="0" right="0" top="1" bottom="1" minWidth="0" minHeight="0">
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:HorizontalLayout paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" paddingTop="3" paddingBottom="3" gap="5" />
                    </s:layout>
                </s:Group>

            </s:Group>

            <!--- @copy spark.components.SkinnableContainer#contentGroup -->
            <s:Group id="contentGroup" width="100%" height="100%" minWidth="0" minHeight="0">
            </s:Group>

            <!--- @private -->
            <s:Group id="bottomGroup" minWidth="0" minHeight="0"
                     includeIn="normalWithControlBar, disabledWithControlBar , disabledWithHeaderBarWithControlBar, normalWithHeaderBarWithControlBar" >

                <s:Group left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" mask="{bottomGroupMask}">

                    <!-- layer 0: control bar divider line -->
                    <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" height="1" alpha="0.22">
                        <s:fill>
                            <s:SolidColor color="0x000000" />
                        </s:fill>
                    </s:Rect>

                    <!-- layer 1: control bar highlight -->
                    <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="1" bottom="0">
                        <s:stroke>
                            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xE5E5E5" />
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xD8D8D8" />
                            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
                        </s:stroke>
                    </s:Rect>

                    <!-- layer 2: control bar fill -->
                    <s:Rect left="1" right="1" top="2" bottom="1">
                        <s:fill>
                            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xDADADA" />
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xC5C5C5" />
                            </s:LinearGradient>
                        </s:fill>
                    </s:Rect>
                </s:Group>
                <!-- layer 3: control bar -->
                <!--- @copy spark.components.Panel#controlBarGroup -->
                <s:Group id="controlBarGroup" left="0" right="0" top="1" bottom="1" minWidth="0" minHeight="0">
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:HorizontalLayout paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" paddingTop="3" paddingBottom="3" gap="10" />
                    </s:layout>
                </s:Group>
            </s:Group>
        </s:Group>
    </s:Group>
</s:SparkSkin>
```

The Application :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" 
               xmlns:panelWithHeader="components.panelWithHeader.*">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import components.panelWithHeader.skin.PanelWithHeaderBarSkin;

            import mx.controls.Alert;

            protected function btnRabbit_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show("You clicked Header bar button");
            }

            protected function btnCat_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show("You clicked Control bar button");
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:HGroup verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0">

        <s:Panel height="300" width="400">
        </s:Panel>

        <panelWithHeader:PanelWithHeaderBar skinClass="components.panelWithHeader.skin.PanelWithHeaderBarSkin"
                                            height="300" width="400"
                                            title="Panel with header and control bar">
            <panelWithHeader:headerBarContent >
                <s:Button label="RABBIT" id="btnRabbit" click="btnRabbit_clickHandler(event)"/>
                <s:DropDownList>
                    <s:dataProvider>
                        <s:ArrayList source="[One,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six,Seven,Eight,Nine,Ten]" />
                    </s:dataProvider>
                </s:DropDownList>
            </panelWithHeader:headerBarContent>

            <panelWithHeader:controlBarContent >
                <s:Button label="CAT" id="btnCat" click="btnCat_clickHandler(event)"/>
            </panelWithHeader:controlBarContent>

        </panelWithHeader:PanelWithHeaderBar>

        <panelWithHeader:PanelWithHeaderBar skinClass="components.panelWithHeader.skin.PanelWithHeaderBarSkin"
                                            height="300" width="400"
                                            title="Panel with TabBar and ButtonBar">
            <panelWithHeader:headerBarContent >
                <s:VGroup width="100%" gap="3" >
                    <s:TabBar width="100%" dataProvider="{myViewStack}">
                        <!--<mx:ArrayCollection>
                            <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
                            <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
                            <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
                            <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
                        </mx:ArrayCollection>-->
                    </s:TabBar>
                    <s:ButtonBar width="100%" dataProvider="{myViewStack02}">
                        <!--<mx:ArrayCollection>
                        <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
                        <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
                        <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
                        <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
                        </mx:ArrayCollection>-->
                    </s:ButtonBar>
                </s:VGroup>
            </panelWithHeader:headerBarContent>

            <s:VGroup height="100%" width="100%">

                <mx:ViewStack id="myViewStack" borderStyle="solid" width="100%" height="100%">

                    <s:NavigatorContent id="search" label="Search">
                        <s:Label text="Search Screen"/>
                    </s:NavigatorContent>

                    <s:NavigatorContent id="custInfo" label="Customer Info">
                        <s:Label text="Customer Info"/>
                    </s:NavigatorContent>

                    <s:NavigatorContent id="accountInfo" label="Account Info">
                        <s:layout>
                            <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"/>
                        </s:layout>
                        <s:Label text="Account Info"/>
                    </s:NavigatorContent>
                </mx:ViewStack>

                <mx:ViewStack id="myViewStack02" borderStyle="solid" width="100%" height="100%">

                    <s:NavigatorContent id="search02" label="Search 02">
                        <s:Label text="Search Screen 02"/>
                    </s:NavigatorContent>

                    <s:NavigatorContent id="custInfo02" label="Customer Info 02">
                        <s:layout>
                            <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"/>
                        </s:layout>
                        <s:Label text="Customer Info 02"/>
                    </s:NavigatorContent>

                    <s:NavigatorContent id="accountInfo02" label="Account Info 02">
                        <s:Label text="Account Info 02"/>
                    </s:NavigatorContent>
                </mx:ViewStack>

            </s:VGroup>

        </panelWithHeader:PanelWithHeaderBar>

    </s:HGroup>

</s:Application>
```